# Force browser to display PDF file instead of download

Tags: php, html, pdf

I found some solution for my issue by googling but none of them worked for me. I want to show a PDF file in a webpage but browser makes user to download it! How can I solve this? My code is below.

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['src'];
$file= 'usr/'.$name.'/out.pdf'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<page size="A4"><embed src=<?php echo $file?> type="application/pdf" width="800px" height="1100px" /></page>
</html>
```

Comment: Check if your server sends the pdf with a `Content-Disposition` header set to `inline`. If it's set to `attachment` the browser will automatically download the file instead of displaying it.

Comment: You can add `target = "_blank"` but if the user doesn't have a browser that supports viewing it there, it will still ask them to download it.

Comment: That's not really relevant. A pdf sent with an `attachment` disposition will automatically start downloading as a file. It doesn't matter what you do... set at as an href of an `<a>` tag... set it as the `src` of an `iFrame` or `embed`... whatever. It won't display. It will be downloaded as a file. iFrames and embeds will stay empty.

Comment: The fact that a pdf file located in a server and should be downloaded to be seen by client is true! But I have seen some websites that pdf files be LOADED BY BROWSER, load page by page and can be seen in browser but browser do not force to download file in your device and ....

Comment: Even videos and audios can be played in browser without download ! There should be a way for pdf files too !

Comment: Did you check the headers your server sends? Try putting the link here and look at the `content-disposition` header https://tools.keycdn.com/curl

Comment: @volf my website is still in xampp it is not public.

Comment: open the network tab in your browser devtools, load your site and page the pdf is supposed to show on, look for the pdf request in the network tab and click on it. It will show you the request/response headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240552/discussion-between-volt-and-saeid-eisakhani).